# RegEx: 2 double quote enclose string search in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I try for the following string:

```
text = '"Some Text","Some Text","18.3",""I Love You, Dad"","","","Some Text"'
result = re.findall(r'""[^"]+""', text)
```

this result returns the following list
['""I Love You, Dad""', '"",""']

but i only want the 1st item of the list how can i remove the 2nd item from the regex. Here the "I Love you, Dad" is variable any string can be enclosed in 2 double quote.
the condition here is: String enclose with 2 double quote.

Comment: `,` is also a string. What are your exact requirements? At least one letter/digit?

Comment: is there any way to remove that , from regex and result will be start with 2 double quote + start with A-Z a-z. Need to add condition that not start with comma

Comment: `re.findall(r'(?<![^,])""([A-Za-z].*?)""(?![^,])', text)`? See https://regex101.com/r/vgaIIH/2

Comment: yes exactly i want this. thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
re.findall(r'(?<![^,])""([A-Za-z].*?)""(?![^,])', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vgaIIH/2). *Details*:

- `(?<![^,])` - a left comma boundary (start of string or a char other than a comma required immediately to the left of the current location)
- `""` - two double quotes
- `([A-Za-z].*?)` - Group 1: an ASCII letter (use `[^\W\d_]` to match any Unicode letter) and then any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `""` - two double quotes
- `(?![^,])` - a right comma boundary (end of string or a char other than a comma required immediately to the right of the current location)

Comment: How about just `""\b(.*)\b""` or maybe `""\b([^"]*)\b""`. Not saying your solution doesn't work. I'm genuinely interested in your opinion.

Comment: @Buttered_Toast I am only answering based on the requirements. OP says "start with 2 double quote + start with A-Z a-z.". `\b` would be too generic here.

Answer (score -1):

re.findall() method finds all instances of a text.
re.search() method either returns None (if the pattern doesn’t match), or a re.MatchObject that contains information about the matching part of the string. This method stops after the first match

```
import re;
text = '"Some Text","Some Text","18.3",""I Love You, Dad"","","","Some Text"'
result = re.search(r'""[^"]+""', text)
if result != None: 
    print("% s" % (result.group(0)))
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but i need the regex result will be one....if its more than one results and get by index its not work in my case....it should one result return from regex. the condition is 2 double quote enclose with text not enclose with comma